# how to keep history of all outputs a user receives when inputting in a program

Tags: python, list

I need to keep track of inputs in my program and store the outputs in a list so they can be replayed(printed out in the end to keep track of the program.

```
history=[]
def get_input():
    global history
    answer=input("enter:")
    history.append(answer)
    if answer=="off":
        print("hi")
    else:
        if answer=="forward":
            print("moved forward")
        elif answer=="back":
            print("moved back")
        answer=get_input()
        #history.append(answer)
    return history
print(get_input())
```

I tried doing this but it only returned the actual inputs and not the outputs they led to.

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_input(history):
    answer = input("enter:")
    history.append(answer)
    if answer == "off":
        print("hi")
        return history
    else:
        if answer == "forward":
            print("moved forward")
        elif answer == "back":
            print("moved back")
        return get_input(history)

print(get_input([]))
```

```
enter:forward
moved forward
enter:back
moved back
enter:off
hi
['forward', 'back', 'off']
```